# pandas dataframe sub setting on multiple loop conditions

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas df having users and their answers to a survey and a score eg

```
Userid  incomebracket  insurance-knowledge..... score 
123         3                3                      56
346         4                6                      65
```

Assume income bracket has 6 levels with 1:1000-5000,6:100000+,similarly insurance-knowledge has 6 levels (1:very little to 6:expert)

Now I have another df which has user profile features like 
userid,age,gender,education....(10 such features)

Now I iterate through set of users (first `df`) and for each of them want to get the entire subset of other users who have the same user profile but higher answer on each column of first `df`, say income. I am doing this using the following say for 3 profile features like age, gender and education

```
df_sameusergroup=df[(df['PPGENDER']==sameuser_gender.values[0])
                & (df['EDUC']==sameuser_educ.values[0])
                & (df['age']==sameuser_agecat.values[0])
                & (df['incomebracket']>user_feature.values[0])]
```

Although this works the profile features here are hardcoded and is a problem for longer conditions,what I want is 
get the subset of users who have same profile on all 10 but with higher answer, if you don't get any such record (which is possible) the reduce to 9 features,then reduce to 8,7.....2 (of the most important features say age gender). My pseudocode for this should look like this

```
for i in range(10:2) // iterate the Userprofile_df for all profile features,then 9,then 8...

Similaruserdf[] = df[subset when all i features are same and income is >]
if(Similaruserdf.length==0)//no such users with all features same 
continue loop reduce number of features to match on 
else
return Similaruserdf[]
```

I am stuck trying to do this and have been looking throughout to find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: the format of the first df is like this ("Userid": [123,246],"incomebracket":[3,4], "Insuranceknowledge":[4,6],"score":[56.65])

Comment: Any help with this would be highly appreciated as I am still stuck.